# Trying to open developer options with small coding test

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, sha256

I am trying to open up the Developer Mode of a program called **Scelight**. The program has a little test before it will let you in.

The problem reads:

> Create a .txt file (saved in a specific location) having the hexadecimal representation of the SHA-256 checksum of the decimal representation of the max value of an 8-byte signed integer shifted right by a value of 0x1a and XOR-ed with the hex value CafeBabe.

**My code is:**

```
long a = 9223372036854775807L;
a = a >> 0x1a;
long hex2 = 0xcafebabe;
long out4 = a ^ hex2;
```

**Update:**

Using Eclipse and Java for this code. This is suggested to be used by the developer.

Confirmed by developer that `0xcafebabe` is what is supposed to be used. Within Eclipse though `0xCafeBabe` will give the same result as `0xcafebabe`.

This gives me `-136549677759` as a result, which I then put into the .txt file and save. Unfortunately this is not correct as developer options are not becoming available.

> a0946923280760e172171605e3c85d096ffa39dfbc308161b05b93e77120e453

This is the result for `-136549677759` and it does not work. I believe that we are looking for the checksum of the final result.

Comment: I meant to also add. Am I completely missing something some where? I know that the text within a file will change the checksum of that file.

Comment: Alternatively, this could be a misinterpretation of the instructions;  are you supposed to take the SHA-256 checksum of `max value` or the checksum of the rest of the calcluations?

Comment: You've skipped the SHA-256 step. Also, it's unclear if you need the max int64 or uint64, so try both. Also, it's unclear whether you need to xor with just the number 0xCAFEBABE, or with an 8-fold repetition of its bit pattern, so try both of those too. Plus, it's unclear if the final result should be formatted as decimal digits, hex digits, or just a string of bytes, so try all three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclosure: I'm the author of [Scelight](https://sites.google.com/site/scelight/).*

Notes beforehand: the problem statement does not require you to use Java, any programming language can be used.

---

### Solution in Java

> having the hexadecimal representation of the SHA-256 checksum of...

We need to calculate the SHA-256 checksum of something, and the checksum has to be presented using hexadecimal numbers. Case (lower or upper case letters) in the hexadecimal representation does not matter.

> the max value of an 8-byte signed integer

This is `Long.MAX_VALUE = (1L<<63)-1 = 9223372036854775807L`.

```
long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

> shifted right by a value of 0x1a

```
a >>= 0x1a;
```

> and XOR-ed with the hex value CafeBabe.

You need to use a value of type `long` being `0xcafebabe`. But note that if you use the value `0xcafebabe`, that is a constant of type `int` and if you convert it to `long`, the sign bit will be used to extended it:

```
System.out.printf("%x", (long)0xcafebabe); // Prints ffffffffcafebabe
```

So use a `long` constant:

```
a ^= 0xcafebabeL;
```

The result so far:

```
a = 134033261889
```

> ...having the hexadecimal representation of the SHA-256 checksum of the decimal representation of...

The SHA-256 checksum (exception handling omitted!):

```
byte[] result = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest((""+a).getBytes());
```

<sup>Notes about `String.getBytes()`: yes, it returns the bytes of the string using the platform's default charset. But since the string only contains digits (optionally a negative sign but in our case it is positive), it is ok. In a mission critical application encoding should be specified, something like this: `(""+a).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.</sup>

And the hexadecimal representation:

```
for (byte b : result) {
    System.out.printf("%02x",b);
}
```

Note the `"%02x"` format string, hex representation of a byte must be 2 hex digits, first being `0` if it is equal to or less than `0xf`.

The first 8 characters of the output (trimmed, at least run the code if you want the full output):

```
e0dd2851...
```

**The full runnable code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    a >>= 0x1a;
    a ^= 0xcafebabeL;

    byte[] result = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(("" + a).getBytes());
    for (byte b : result) {
        System.out.printf("%02x", b);
    }
}
```

The full runnable code in "compact" mode:

```
for (byte b : MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        .digest(Long.toString((Long.MAX_VALUE >> 0x1a ^ 0xcafebabeL)).getBytes()))
    System.out.printf("%02x", b);
```

### Solution in Go

Solution in Go is even shorter:

```
a := int64(math.MaxInt64)
a >>= 0x1a
a ^= 0xcafebabe
fmt.Printf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte(fmt.Sprint(a))))
```

And the "compact" one-liner:

```
fmt.Printf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte(fmt.Sprint(int64(1<<63-1)>>0x1a^0xcafebabe))))
```

The Go solutions can be tried on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/yrMqgtulot).

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the great answer! Just took a look at the inspector tab. The path has just begun.